# Spritekit SK3DNode antialiasing / jittering

Tags: swift, scenekit, antialiasing, multisampling

I'd like to use antialiasing for 3D objects displayed through an SK3DNode.

I've skimmed through the documentation but apparently there is no easy flag to set multisampling for the SceneKit renderer that is used for an SK3DNode. Usually, these flags are set on an SCNView but is there possibly a way to retrieve the SCNRenderer and set it there?

Or maybe I'd have to use offscreen rendering to a metal texture and display that inside an SKSpriteNode?

Comment: As I see in documentation if you will be able to use SKTexture for SK3DNode than you can change - filteringMode for particular node.

Comment: filteringMode on the texture is for texture scaling (it's not actually filtering anything). That has nothing to do with antialiasing.

Comment: any progress here?